# I want to hide button after clicking on action method

Tags: ios, xcode

My Sample code:

```
- (IBAction)captureButton:(id)sender {

    captureButton.hidden = YES;

    currImage = [signatureViewController imageWithView:self.view];
    NSLog (@"image %@",currImage);
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,100,300,150)];
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     imgView.image = currImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    image.image = nil;
}
```

My prob is capturebutton is geting hidden the view.. please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: delete the line "image.image = nil;"

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? why you are setting this image.image = nil???

Comment: That is for clearing the signature in the main UIView before capturing it into currImage @Anil

Comment: While Capturing the whole view my button is also geting captured into the subview so i dont want dat...@Anil

Answer (score 3):

**Two options:**

1) Add the following code to bring your image view to front:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
```

2) Hide your button:

```
[(UIButton *)sender setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`yourButton.hidden = YES;`

Comment: As you can see dat in my sample code its not wrkng..Thanks..@krunal

Comment: While Capturing the whole view my button is also geting captured into the subview want to hide the button after clicking

Answer (score 0):

You could just try disabling the button. 
If it is hidden behind a view this may help.

yourbutton.enabled = NO;