# Making a button invisible after clicking it?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to know how to make a button that starts the gameplay and right after the gameplay starts the button must disappear from the view and can't be touchable.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hide it.  (Hint:  Check the documentation for UIView.)

Comment: `[myButton setHidden:YES];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to hide button after clicking on action method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605654/i-want-to-hide-button-after-clicking-on-action-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also do it by setting its alpha value to zero. try this!

```
[self.buttonName setAlpha:0];
```

and again on changing it to one will unhide the button.

```
[self.buttonName setAlpha:1];
```

hope this serves your purpose. Happy coding!.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite simple make sure you have both the outlet and Action property of UIButton. In the .h file.

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)UIButton *clickMeButton;
-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender;
```

Now implement the hide code in the .m file

```
-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender
 {
     clickMeButton.hidden=YES;
 }
```

I hope this will work for you .